# Opening .aspx file as partial view of cshtml in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

I try to use ReportViewer in my MVC app.

I Have View that have button :

```
<button id="ReprintBol" class="button secondary right noPrint" style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0">
    <span class="noPrint" style="display: inline-block; padding: 0 0 0 10px; font-size: 11px; font-weight: bold;">Reprint</span>
</button>
```

Aspx File as partial view :

```
@Html.Partial("ReportViewer")
```

And code to handle button click :

```
<script>

$('#ReprintBol').click(function () {
    $("#Test").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        resizable: false,
        width: 700,
        height: 400,
        modal: true,
        title: 'Note',
        autoOpen: false,
        draggable: true,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "blind",
        bDestroy: true,
        overlay: {
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            opacity: 0.5
        },
    });
    $("#Test").dialog("option", "title", "Select Stops");
    $("#Test").dialog("open");
});

</script>
```

My aspx view

```
<div id="Test" style="display: none">

   <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
 </asp:ScriptManager>
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Height="509px" Width="1542px">
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
</form> 
</div>
```

When i try to run this code and hit button just error show and say that javascript have errors. I have checked it 10 times and don't see any.
What i do wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: what exactly error said?

Comment: Also as i know you can't just render your `.aspx` page with `@Html.Partial` helper.

Comment: The error said : `0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined` and i also add the controler to this view so `@HTML.partial` should work

Comment: Is the Jquery referred correctly?

Comment: Yes this page is much bigger and every part that use jquery work fine

Comment: Pls add  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js">  in this script tag & check..It works for me after removing the trailing comma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there is additional "," at the end of this block :

```
$("#Test").dialog({
        bgiframe: true,
        resizable: false,
        width: 700,
        height: 400,
        modal: true,
        title: 'Note',
        autoOpen: false,
        draggable: true,
        show: "blind",
        hide: "blind",
        bDestroy: true,
        overlay: {
            backgroundColor: '#000',
            opacity: 0.5
        }**,**
    });
```

Also add type to script tag like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
```

Comment: that shouldn't be the problem

Comment: The problem still exist

Comment: @Aht I tried it ,and it worked after adding type to script tag : <script type="text/javascript" >